# Drupal - stop node/nid access

Tags: drupal, path

How to prevent users from also using the node/nid path or the index.php?q= one. In other words ... there should be just ONE path to a page / node... not several.

My path uses a sha1 hash by using the pathauto module... it is random. It should prevent users from testing for node existence.

Is there a module that prompts an "access denied" when accessing the node in any other way than the pathauto alias?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the pathaccess module. 
In my case it stops access to everything for anonymous users apart from the first segment of my pathauto path (path/*).

Works.